# How do I track what users are opening and downloading in SharePoint 2013 Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

Given that the "Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item properties" audit event is unavailable in SP2013 Online, what other options are there for tracking who is opening or downloading what? Why is this even disabled in SP Online?

Source: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/View-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527

[image: opening and downloading audit unavailable in SP Online]

Comment: What is your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same limitation before. Unfortunately, this feature is not activated for SharePoint Online and is highly discouraged to be activated for On-Premise. The reason behind is it will create a huge amount of logs that could potentially fill up the space limitation of your site collection.

For more info, refer to this [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2).

Comment: Many thanks, I'd come to the same conclusion. I can see why MS have disabled this feature entirely for SP Online.

Answer (score 1):

One approach,You can implement SPAudit class within a console application, run it as a windows task scheduler on a daily basis and generate a report in a .txt file.

Comment: Does this work with SP Online?